# Display CodeLens above attributes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, codelens

It is quite annoying to see codelens reference between the field and field's attributes. It requires to add a lot of additional spaces around to make everything readable. Is it possible to display CodeLens reference above the attributes?

[image]

Comment: If found that the most effective way to deal with the visual clutter generated by Codelens was to just disable it.

Comment: @HansPassant, I agree. But I like the features of codeLens

Comment: The features of CodeLens are not CodeLens features.  Find All References is in the context menu and Ctrl+K,R on my keyboard.

Comment: true, but that's only find all references.  there are a bunch of other indicators that are not other features.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible.

If you'd like to see this, I suggest you give the product team a shout-out on the [Visual Studio UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) and post back the link as a comment to this answer. I'd suggest not to move the code lens information, but to suggest the location to be made configurable :).

Though I can't disclose any details, I've seen your feedback before and I know it has been considered, but rejected.

Comment: Please vote!  https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/9135343-show-codelens-above-attributes-if-they-exists

Comment: Previous request was declined, new request: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/19877623

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question but as an update to @jessehouwing this is Visual Studio team answer:

> Dear supporters for this suggestion
>
> Thank you for your feedback on this idea.
>
> We designed the Code Lens indicator to be as close to the actual
> function declaration as possible, to allow you to make a better
> cognitive connection with it. At one point during the development of
> Code Lens, we actually tried locating it above the attributes as this
> suggestion requests. It looked great in simple cases, but
> unfortunately it started to feel “disconnected” from the declaration
> when more attributes were added. It really looked strange at around
> three attributes, but started feeling a bit odd around two.
>
> Here’s a pathological “real world” case which illustrates this -
>
> https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/VisualStudio/CSharp/Impl/CSharpPackage.cs#L26
>
> Imagine the indicator above the attributes in this case.
>
> For this reason, we’re declining this suggestion at present.
>
> Thanks! Mark Wilson-Thomas Program Manager, Visual Studio Editor Team

So sadly it won't be fixed, but after reading the whole answer, I have to agree.

Comment: I don't. The most common case is 1-2 attributes, not a full page thereof.

Comment: Isn't this why `if` was invented? (ok so you lose consistency but I wanted to make the cheeky remark so couldn't help myself) ...  but I think I'd be happy with "if one attribute" put it above attributes otherwise above method name

Comment: Fun fact: in Roslyn code analysis, attributes *are* part of the "actual function declaration" (`MethodDeclarationSyntax`). By their own logic, they should honor this request.